# How to call MATLAB from the command line several times, using the same MATLAB instance every time

Tags: matlab, command-line

I have a .m script that is called from the Windows command line (aka or prompt), and I call this script with different arguments several times (50+) a day.

I tried using the `matlab -r "run script.m"` and the script is correctly executed, but everytime I issue this prompt command a new instance of MATLAB is opened, which is undesirable in this case.

Is there a way of identifying that there is an instance of MATLAB already running on my Windows 7 machine, and force the use of the same MATLAB instance on several external calls via Windows command line?

Comment: You can control matlab through [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) see [here](http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/call-matlab-com-automation-server.html). I'm not sure about the command line capabilities - but you can definitely use powershell to control it.

Comment: @bdecaf: +1 good suggestion. In fact with the COM interface, you can reuse existing sessions to execute scripts (without creating new ones each time)

Comment: In fact I want MATLAB Simulink to hilite a block (using hilite_system command), trigged by commands external to MATLAB. For that, the _nodesktop_ and _minimize_ options would not work for what I need. I will have a look at the COM interface! Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102082-how-do-i-call-matlab-from-the-dos-prompt), you cannot prevent MATLAB from creating a window when starting on Windows systems, however, you can force the window to be hidden, by using the start command with the `-nodesktop` and `-minimize` options together:

```
start matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -minimize -r "run script.m"
```

or simply

```
start matlab -nosplash -nodesktop -minimize -r script
```

PS: Although this will prevent creating new instances of MATLAB (full IDE), this still will create the same number of MATLAB command windows (MATLAB processes) instead.

Comment: Just to clarify your last statement: it will still launch a new MATLAB process each time to execute the script, just without opening the full IDE